# .vimrc causes error (E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &)

Tags: vim, fedora

I've copy pasted [this .vimrc](http://amix.dk/vim/vimrc.html) into my /etc/vimrc in Fedora 15. Every time I use vim for anything, I get a number of errors with line numbers which don't seem to be the correct line numbers of my vimrc file because there aren't any '\'s on those lines.

I've googled this and there is a similar stack overflow question, but I believe it is irrelevant to my question.

I also removed everything that said `MySys() == linux/max/windows` or etc because I'm using linux so I just used the linux lines.

Any ideas?

Edit---

Here's my (barely) modified vimrc file:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PznK0FizGlBr6W6m9wikM334q8b6KFFCgmsF-f8MX3s/edit?hl=en_US

Comment: I posted a link. Want the one with my minor modifications?

Comment: Yep, it would be better if you post `vimrc` with your modifications, also check maybe you have local `~/.vimrc` with this errors.

Comment: I believe Fedora only picks up the vimrc at /etc/vimrc. That's what is under FILES when I run man vim.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Error you mentioned here normally happens in one of the following cases:

1. You are trying to use line continuation inside `:execute`.
2. You are trying to use line continuation when vim is in compatible mode.

To remove the second case run vim using `vim -N`. If no errors appear, add `set nocompatible` at the top of the vimrc. If errors still appear, search for `exe` (as `:execute` can be truncated to `:exe`) and check out whether somewhere line matching `\n\s*\\` is passed to `:execute`.

Comment: It was the compatibile mode. Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you mean by "search for exe"? Inside VIM or inside some plugins or the `~/.vim` directory?

Comment: @Zelphir Inside the offending (which triggered the error after being added/updated) vim scripts.

Comment: @ZyX I followed the other suggestion you made, to add the `set nocompatible` to my `.vimrc` and that worked. The issue only appeared after upgrading to vim 8.0 and i did not change any of my plugins. Seems like vim 7.4 from the repos did not have this issue.